# Ubutu Core on Rasberry Pi 4 8Gb: trying to SSH into it, and I am being denied? (using PuTTY)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core

The SSH key was created using PuTTY Key Gen is 4028 RSA.It is saved on my SSO on login.ubuntu.com.

When I set up the Ubuntu Core it says that my device is registered to my email and that my authentication is set with my SSO user.

I followed these instructions:
https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-login-into-ubuntu-using-ssh-from-windows-10-8-7.html

So I figured the PuTTY client would work on Core as well.  Am I wrong in assuming this?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I decided to try another client and this one gave me more data:

Starting a new connection to: "192.168.1.171" port "22"

- ⚙️ Starting address resolution of "192.168.1.171"
- ⚙️ Address resolution finished
- ⚙️ Connecting to "192.168.1.171" port "22"
- Connection to "192.168.1.171" established
- ⚙️ Starting SSH session
- ⚙️ Remote server: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
- ⚙️ Agreed KEX algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
- ⚙️ Agreed Host Key algorithm: ssh-rsa
- ⚙️ Agreed server-to-client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256
- ⚙️ Agreed client-to-server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256
- ⚙️ Handshake finished
- Checking host key: *edited out*
- Host "192.168.1.171":"22" is known and matches
- Authenticating to "192.168.1.171":"22" as "cyberpawz"
- ❗ Disabling authentication using publickey: Private Key is empty
- Available client authentication methods: password,keyboard-interactive
- ⚙️ Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
- Authenticating using password method
- ❗ Authentication failed (password)

Comment: One possible reason may be Putty uses a different key format that may not be recognized by the Ubuntu SSO system. See [this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-pem-and-ppk/) for the format differences. Try converting the `ppk` keys to `pem` format and upload them again in `https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys`.

Comment: @user68186 I just tried that, I utilized PowerShell, and no love.  I am going to have to try installing the server and seeing if it matters. I am honestly getting annoyed at this.  This should be "simple" but it's not.

Comment: I am sorry it didn't work. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator. 
1. The connection will be stable, the Raspberry Pi is on my network and I have given it a static IP via my router. 

2. You will have to trust that I followed it, because there is no reason why I would NOT and then come here for help.

3. The errors are simple, password incorrect. That's it.

Comment: "Password incorrect" is very different from "access denied" error. If you have private/public keys setup then you should not get "password incorrect" error. Have you tried using the Windows `ssh` command from the powershell? You may have to create and upload the public key again. See this [instruction](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/generate-ssh-key-windows-10)

Comment: @user68186 Updated main question.  I found a new client with a better log system.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the ssh client says "Private Key is empty". Why is that?

Comment: @user68186 I have no clue, the private key is on ubuntu's website.. for SSO

Comment: That is the problem. The private key should never be shared. The public key should be on Ubuntu website. The private key must be in your computer where putty or the the other ssh client you are using now can find it.

Comment: Delete the private key from the Ubuntu website unusually. Keeping it there is like broadcasting your password to anyone who wants it.

Comment: @user68186 I did after it didn't work, but my problem is that both don't work, and the shh files are on my PC... it's driving me nuts why this isn't working.